# Setting the XAML content of a control to a property of that control

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a user control as such:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty pageContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PageContent", typeof(UIElement), typeof(ActionPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public UIElement PageContent
    {
        get { return (UIElement)base.GetValue(pageContentProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(pageContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // More code
}
```

Now if I use it in XAML I have to do:

```
<l:MyControl>
    <l:MyControl.PageContent>
         <TextBlock Text="Lorum Ipsum"/>
    </l:MyControl.PageContent>
</l:MyControl>
```

But I want to just do:

```
<l:MyControl>
    <TextBlock Text="Lorum Ipsum"/>
</l:MyControl>
```

Currently if I do this it replace the entire content of the control with the `TextBlock` (which makes sense for a normal `UserControl`) but how can I override this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try adding the `ContentProperty` attribute to your `PageContent` property:-

```
[ContentProperty("PageContent")]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
```

Comment: The ContentProperty cannot be applied to a property but need to be applied to the class. So I just moved the property to the class definition as 
`[ContentProperty("PageContent")] public partical class MyControl` 
and it worked. Thanks for sending me on the right track. I'm marking your answer as the answer but perhaps just modify it for future references.
Thanks again.

Comment: Hi AnthonyWJones!
How can i set directly in xaml with when ContentProperty is a collection.